# How can I create a MediaController instance from MediaSessionManager?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to move from RemoteController to MediaController for Lollipop but I'm having trouble getting a MediaController instance. In MediaController it says:

> A MediaController can be created through MediaSessionManager if you hold the "android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" permission or are an enabled notification listener or by getting a MediaSession.Token directly from the session owner.

However when I look at MediaSessionManager there are no methods other than addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener, getActiveSessions, and removeOnActiveSessionsChangedListener these help me none.
I tried creating a token from a MediaSession but that didn't enable my callback to get anything from other media players.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager.html#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)) gives you a list of `MediaController` instances associated with the currently playing music player(s). You can then use [MediaController.registerCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html#registerCallback(android.media.session.MediaController.Callback)) to register a [MediaController.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html) implementation you've created, which has similar callbacks to the deprecated [RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener.html) (or just send media controls directly back to the `MediaController`.

Of course, in most cases you want to keep your list of `MediaController`s in sync with the system: that is what [MediaSessionManager.addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager.html#addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener,%20android.content.ComponentName)) is for: it gives you an updated list of `MediaController`s with which to use and is called every time the list of players change. As per the documentation, if you are using the permission you can pass `null` in for the `ComponentName notificationListener` parameter.

Comment: I tried: List<MediaController> controllers = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), "ListenerService.class"));
Also fails if I try to pass null. Error: "java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to control media." I have the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>

Comment: So you have a NotificationListenerService? It has access to notifications (check Settings->Sound & Notifications->Notification Access)? Also you should use `new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ListenerService.class)` (no quotes) as the string version assumes a fully qualified class name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Needed to do ListenerService.class.getName() but its working

Comment: Ah, I figured you'd just use the [ComponentName constructor that takes a Class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class<?>)), but if that works, great!

Comment: @ianhanniballake, for me one custom music player is there in my launcher app, I tried `mMediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(null)` to get on going session list, but this `getActiveSessions` is returning empty list after reboot. so I could not play eny music even after clicking play button. Any hop for solving this issue. Thanks in advance ..!

Comment: @Navaspk it is called `getActiveSessions` for a reason - it is only expect to return active sessions, not apps that have long since stopped playback.

Comment: you mean after reboot `getActiveSessions()` will not return active session right?
Okay, is there any way to get play back ..?

Comment: @Navaspk - per the [Media Session Callbacks docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks.html), apps are only active after they start playback through when they are stopped. It is only during that time that you'll be able to interact with them via the `MediaSessionManager` APIs.

Comment: Note that the permission mentioned for `addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener` is restricted for system and vendor apps only